# convert laTeX to semantic LaTeX Format

Tags: javascript, semantics

I'm very new in Math,LaTex and all those Related things.

Recently I worked on [Guppy.js](https://guppy.js.org) .

And they have option to export [laTex](https://guppy.js.org/site/api/guppy-js/2.0.0-beta.1/Doc.html#get_content).

But when I try to [Import the LaTex](https://guppy.js.org/site/api/guppy-js/2.0.0-beta.1/Guppy.html#import_latex) it gives an Error.

Reading docs they just allow to put `semantic LaTeX` format.

They don't have a methode to convert `LaTex` to `semantic LaTeX`.

See the Example page of Guppy.JS

[Import semantic LaTeX Export SVG](https://guppy.js.org/site/examples/io/)

For Example I  Import below `semantic LaTeX` format.

```
\defintegral{1}{2}{x^2}{x}
```

It will Give the latex back.

```
 \displaystyle\int_{ 1  }^{ 2  }  { x  }^{ 2  }    d x
```

I Just wanted to convert this `laTeX` to `semantic LaTeX`.

-Thanks in advance

Comment: the "semantic latex" isn't a generally defined format it's a specific input format for the guppy system as far as I can see. Of course in general converting from a structured/semantic format to general latex is much easier than the reverse direction which will not, in general, be possible.

Comment: Hi David,is there any option for this.

Comment: as I say I doubt it but I have no idea about guppy other than looking at the link you gave for a few minutes. Your question though is just about that system not really anything a general latex site can help with. You should ask the maintainers.

Comment: Ok , Thank you for trying to help me. As you said I will check with their system .